# Magento admin for manufacturer to update status

Tags: magento

Someone I know has an ecommerce site, and she said it's done w Magento. However, in addition to the regular admin for the store owner, there's an additional admin for her manufacturer(s) to login and update the production status and the order status, even printing out address label for shipping - like the screenshots below.

By the look, it looks like it's a generic admin area of some application. Do you know if there's an extension or something like that that does this or this was a custom development? I know my question is vague, but I want to explore doing something similar and not sure where to start.
Thanks for the input!

[image: Admin for manufacturer to update status]

[image: Admin for manufacturer to update status]

Answer (score 0):

You can use Magento ACL rules to define admin user groups and allow specific actions to those groups:

> https://yourmagento.com/index.php/admin/permissions_role/index/

You may need to add custom code to restrict manufacturers to only update their own orders/products.